# Apply a custom percentile function in rolling rows over a dataframe without loop - R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe with 10k rows and 150 columns. I want to apply a rolling custom function to calculate the percentile rank using a simple percentile rank function (`function(x, xo) sum(x <= xo,na.rm = T)/sum(!is.na(x))`), where x is a dataframe of numeric values and xo is the value I want to calculate the rank on. The problem is that I am currently using a loop and takes a massive amount of time. The reason i am using a loop is that the function is applied on dynamically changing number of rows of the dataframe. Is there a way to avoid the loop and save some time? This process takes around 71 seconds and i need to run it for 250 different datasets (around 5 hrs in total).

I have tried using apply functions but with no result.

```
ptm <- proc.time()
function(x, xo) sum(x <= xo,na.rm = T)/sum(!is.na(x))
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(data= runif(1:1000),nrow = 10000,ncol=150))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data= runif(1:1000),nrow = 10000,ncol=1))
df[,1:150] <- runif(1:10000)
colnames(df) <- c("Value_to_Rank","Percent.Range1","Percent.Range2","Percent.Range3") # named only 4 columns
for (i in c(1:nrow(BetaTotal))){
    df2[i,1] <- perc.rank(df[1:i,3:150],df[i,2])
 }
   proc.time() - ptm


   user  system elapsed 
  71.46    0.23   72.67
```

Any efficiency is appreciated! I tried adding another column with the "rollwindow" element (in this case i) and subset based on that, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Why not use `*apply`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I tried *apply but cannot get it work.

Comment: I mean use the `apply` family instead of rewriting the loop from "scratch".

Comment: Can you please provide an example? I am not familiar at all with apply family of functions

Comment: Did you ever try running that code of yours? This is not a reproducible example. In case you wonder why you never received an answer...